# Firebase Android: What is the difference between getting callback from DatabaseReference's setValue via Task and DatabaseReference.CompletionListener?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using the post-Google I/O 2016 Firebase database.

On a `DatabaseReference`, there is two similar methods, seem to only differ by the completion callback.

One is  `void setValue(Object value, DatabaseReference.CompletionListener listener)`, and another is `Task<Void> setValue(Object value)`.

Are they interchangeable? The docs does not say anything about it and the Firebase Android SDK is closed source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are *almost* interchangeable.  The key difference between the Task returned by setValue and the passed CompletionListener is the ability to avoid object leaks.

When you pass a CompletionListener to setValue, the Firebase SDK will hold on to that object reference (and all of *that* object's strong references, and so on) indefinitely, until the data is finally written at the server side.  For Android apps, this can be particularly problematic because you could end up leaking an Activity reference, which is pretty expensive.

When you use a Task, you have the ability to add and remove listeners from *that* as needed, so if you're no longer interested in knowing if a write succeeded, you can free up the objects that were previously interested.  In Android, there are overloads for adding listeners that automatically let a listener remove itself when the activity is stopped, so you don't have to arrange to do that yourself.

With Tasks, you can also arrange to have your callback invoked on a particular Executor, which is a convenient way to kick intense work off to another thread.  With, CompletionListener, you'd have to arrange for that yourself in the callback itself.

I have a [four-part blog series](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-1.html) on the Tasks that are provided by Play services and the Java admin SDK.  There is also [formal documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks).

Comment: Thanks for the clear and detailed answer! I'm so glad that the Firebase team member himself monitors and answers StackOverflow questions!

Comment: I was wondering if the (2) mentioned methods here are safer to use and less prone to memory leaks over addChildEventListener, addListenerForSingleValueEvent and addValueEventListener used in database references? Thanks.

Comment: Those listeners will not leak if you take care to remove them before their context goes away.  It's your responsibility. Task listeners are the same way, except if you use the variety that takes an Activity, you don't have to worry about removing their listeners.